# Implementing recursive aggregation

Tags: c#, aggregation

I am creating an applicaiton that requires the use of recursive aggregation in one of the classes. The class at hand is entitiled "component" and a component may be made up of sub components stored within a list. The following code shows this.

```
    public class Component {
//vars for class
public String componentName;
public String componentShape;
public String componentColour;
public String componentMaterial;
public int numChildComps;

//list to store child components of component
public List<Component> childComponents;

public Component(string _componentName, string _componentShape, string _componentColour, string _componentMaterial, int _numChildComps)
{
    componentName = _componentName;
    componentShape = _componentShape;
    componentColour = _componentColour;
    componentMaterial = _componentMaterial;
    numChildComps = _numChildComps;

    //if component has no child components set list to null
    if (numChildComps == 0)
    {
        //instatiate new list
        childComponents = new List<Component>();
        childComponents = null;
    }
    else if(numChildComps != 0)//if not null then create child components for the amount stated above.
    {
        childComponents = new List<Component>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numChildComps; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add details for child component " + (i+1));
            Console.WriteLine("Enter component Name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter shape: ");
            string shape = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Colour: ");
            string colour = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Material: ");
            string material = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter num child components: ");
            string num = Console.ReadLine();
            childComponents.Add(new Component(name, shape, colour, material, Int16.Parse(num)));//instatiate new child component with params and add to the list.
        }
    }
}
```

This will instaiated a class and if the parameter for number fo child components is more than 0 then it will create the object and store it in the list "childComponents". This works fine. My question is how would I go about retrieving the items within the list. Take the following as an example, I have a model which is made up of one component but that component has 2 components and one of those has another 2 and one of those has one component:

```
Model
 -component
  -childComponent
    -childComponent
    -childComponent
      -childComponent
  -childComponent
```

Obviously this could go on forever and I have tried creating a piece of code to retireve all the components and sub components but it has not worked as you need to know the total amount of components a model has and then that components childComponents and so on.

Code that I have tried(does not model the above example)

```
    IEnumerable<SEModel> modelres = from SEModel sm in database
                                    select sm;
    foreach (SEModel item in modelres)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(item.getSetModelName);
      Console.WriteLine(item.componentList.First().componentName);
      foreach (SEComponent citem in item.componentList)
      {
       Console.WriteLine(citem.childComponents.First().componentName);
        foreach (SEComponent scitem in citem.childComponents)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(scitem.componentName);
        }
     }
```

Like stated above you would have to know the amount of components with childcomponents and then their childcomponents and so on.

Comment: Please show your code using recursion that doesn't work.

Comment: Well it works if you know the total amount of components with all the child components below it and their childcomponents and so on. Which isn't ideal as the amount of components a model has will be different for every model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Component> GetComponents()
{
    yield return this;

    foreach( var childComp in childComponents )
    {
        foreach( var comp in childComp.GetComponents() )
        {
            yield return comp;
        }
    }
}
```

If you're not sure what `yield return` is all about, [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

Comment: Considering OP struggles with recursion, I don't think `yield return` is appropriate. :) But your code is the most clean solution indeed.

Comment: hey, it's recursive! ;)

Comment: +1 Good solution, just to summarize what `yield return object` is and does, it is a contextual keyword used in iterator methods when implementing enumerators. Basically, it has two use cases: `yield return obj;` returns the next item in the sequence. `yield break;` stops returning sequence elements (this happens automatically if control reaches the end of the iterator method body).

Comment: After looking around and reading this has worked like a charm, thank you for you input, and every one else too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve the components as a flat list you can do it this way:

```
public List<Component> GetAllComponents(List<Component> components)
{
   var result = new List<Component>();
   result.AddRange(components);

   foreach (var component in  components)
        result.AddRange(GetAllComponents(component.childComponents));

   return result;
}

var allComponents = GetAllComponents(Model.Components);
```

Though I am not sure from your question what exactly you want to do.